# Generators for the sheaf of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/392793/3416) I found out that my claim below is wrong in general for abstract varieties (I guess it is true for affine varieties, though). Below you'll find also my wrong naive proof... could you help me to understand where am I using implicitly that $X$ is affine? Or, more generally, to spot the mistakes in  my proof?

**Claim (wrong!)**

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety. Then for $f_i \in \mathcal{O}_X$ we have 
$$ X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_X(f_i) \iff \mathcal{O}_X = (f_1, \dots, f_n) $$

**Proof (wrong!)**

Unwinding the definition of $D_X(f_i)$ we find
$$ X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n D_X(f_i) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n X \setminus \mathcal{Z}(f_i) = X \setminus \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathcal{Z}(f_i) \right) $$
        which implies that
        $$ \emptyset = \bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathcal{Z}(f_i) = \mathcal{Z}( f_1, \dots, f_n ) \iff (f_1, \dots, f_n) = (1) = \mathcal{O}_X. $$

Comment: Why does $\mathcal{Z}(f_1, \dots, f_n) = \emptyset$ imply $(f_1, \dots, f_n) = (1)$?

Comment: The counterexample in your link shows that $\mathcal{Z}(x,y)=\emptyset$ while $(x,y)\neq (1)$ for $X=\mathbb{A}^2-{(0,0)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as pointed out by Brandon and Jerry the very last step of my proof is wrong: for algebraic varieties it's not true in general that
$$
\emptyset = \mathcal{Z}( f_1, \dots, f_n ) \implies (f_1, \dots, f_n) = (1).
$$

Nevertheless the above implication holds for an affine variety. This can be proved using [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz), from which it follows that for ideals $A$ and $B$ we have
$$ \mathcal{Z}(A) = \mathcal{Z}(B) \implies \sqrt{A}=\sqrt{B}. $$
Therefore in the above proof (for an affine variety) this specializes to
$$ \mathcal{Z}(f_i) = \mathcal{Z}(1) \implies \sqrt{(f_i)}=\sqrt{(1)} \implies (f_i) = (1). $$